# How to a mark a function as invalidating its argument

Tags: c++, c++11, types, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have a function `f` that accepts a vector of pointers. Once the function `f` finishes, these pointers are no longer valid. Note, there is no real need to change the vector itself, I just want to encourage callers not to use the pointers after the call to `f`. There are three possible signatures for `f`:

The move signature

```
void f(vector<void*> &&v); // because the pointers in v are no longer valid. 
// This signature also allows me to have f call clear() on v.
```

The const signature

```
void f(const vector<void*> &v); // because the pointers in v are no longer valid,
// but we don't have to change the vector v.
```

The pointer signature

```
void f(vector<void*> *v); // The functino modifies v in a predictable way 
// (it clears it). A pointer is used instead of a reference so that
// calls to the function will have a '&' which clearly shows to the reader
// that this function modifies its argument. '*' is different from '&&' since '&&' 
// may imply "do not use v, but it is unknown how it will be modified" while 
// '*' implies a clear semantic for how v is changed.
```

Which signature is more idiomatic to use in C++11?

Comment: `const vector&` does not let you modify the vector at all and passing a pointer only makes sense if "no argument" is a sensible argument. The first variant does not accept lvalues, which is pretty weird to. Just pass by value and let the caller decide whether he wants a move or a copy.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - I get that. I repeat, my scenario is this, I do not have to change the vector, I just want to use the type of the function to mark to the caller that the pointers in it should no longer be used.

Comment: None of these signatures actually says/guarantees anything about the pointers (let alone the pointees) inside the vector, merely about the vector itself.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - The `&&` signature semantically means "this function may modify `v` to everything that is destructable, so do not rely on the contents of v", that's pretty close, don't you think?

Comment: @tohava No. Like you said, the signature says “do not rely on the contents of the vector” but that’s irrelevant. What if the caller has different pointers which point to the same resource? Your signature would make sense if the pointers denoted ownership (`unique_ptr`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - then it is his problem, I agree it's not perfect, but it is like the practice of some libraries to have their `free` functions get a pointer-to-pointer and then set the pointer to NULL. It is not perfect, but it helps preventing some errors.

Comment: If you don't modify the `vector`, IMHO your function signature imposes too many constraints on the user. Typically, if you don't need to modify a container, you can use iterators / a range instead.

Comment: @tohava The thing isn’t that this is not perfect, it would be actively misleading: Nobody would understand the signature in the way you intend, because the type system simply does not convey this information; your signatures convey a *different*, orthogonal information. You have two choices: either codify it correctly (e.g. by using the afore-mentioned `unique_ptr`s) or don’t attempt to codify it (wrongly) in the type system at all, and rely on documentation & tests instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - and let's say I decided that as part of its semantics, the function calls `clear()` on the array, should I use `&` (without const) or `&&`?

Comment: @tohava If you pass the object as `&&`, then it makes no difference for the outside observer whether `clear` is called or not: the caller has given up the object anyway.

Comment: In that case, `&&` is the best choice

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you will write this as an answer I'll +1 you and mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
void f(vector<void*> v);
```

And to use it:

```
vector<void*> myVec = /*...*/;
f(std::move(myVec));
```

If `f` logically needs ownership of a vector, this is the idiomatic way. It allows the caller to decide whether to move or copy a vector to `f`.

If the caller actually wants `f` to modify his vector (so the vector is actually an in/out argument) then this doesn't suit your needs. However in/out arguments suck. Functions should take input as arguments and return output as a return value. That's what god intended.

Comment: Why is this better than the `&&` version, and how is that any better than my other suggestions? I am trying to understand which of the three is best and why

Comment: The vector is a vector containing pointers/handles/whatever. There is no real need to modify it, but I want to clarify to the caller that he should no longer use these pointers/handles.

Comment: If `f` deletes the pointers then this is the worst option (it will leave the caller with a vector of indeterminate pointers if the caller forgets to write `std::move`)

Comment: You should add a deleted lvalue overload that can prevent accidental non-moving.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this with the type system, it is always possible to encode extra information using your own type.

```
template<class T>
struct invalidates_contained_pointers;

template<class T>
invalidates_contained_pointers<T>* contents_will_be_invalidated(T* ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<invalidates_contained_pointers<T>*>(ptr);
}

void f(invalidates_contained_pointers<vector<void*>> *v){
    auto pv = reinterpret_cast<vector<void*> *>(v);
    // ...
}

f(contents_will_be_invalidated(&vec));
```

A similar approach can be used for references.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: there is no way to do this. The only thing that is 'official' is the inverse: there *is* a signature that promises that a function `f(..)` will NOT change its arguments: the `const` keyword.

Typically one adheres to the following:

- functions that do not modify their arguments either get their arguments as copy-by-value or mark their arguments explicitly with `const`
- arguments that are passed by non-const reference, move or pointer to non-const object should be read as "there is a fair chance this argument is modified by the called function `f(...)`".

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the type system doesn't allow you to indicate something like "don't use this data after this function call". What you *could* do:

```
void f(vector<void*> &v)
{
  // ... use v ...
  v.clear(); // encourage callers not to use the pointers after the call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`f` should clear the vector if it is deleting the pointers (or freeing whatever they are handles to).  It is just pointlessly dangerous to leave the caller with a vector of intederminate values.

So `f` should accept the vector by non-const reference. Whether you want to make this lvalue reference or rvalue reference is up to you; but the lvalue version seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Out of those three: `vector<void*> *` requires an lvalue to take the address of. `const vector<void*> &` allows either lvalues or rvalues to be passed in. `vector<void*> &&` only allows rvalues to be passed in.

Based on your question, your function makes sense to be called with either lvalues or rvalues, so `const vector<void*> &` is the obvious choice.

There is no way to indicate through the type system that the caller should stop using the contained pointers, and you shouldn't try to indicate that through the type system. Indicate that through the documentation.